# Getting database value in smarty template

Tags: smarty

I have php file called `testfun.php`

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("unabke to connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("smartyform",$conn) or die("databse error");

require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$sel=mysql_query("select * from form"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
$id=$row[0];
$name=$row[1];
}
$smarty->assign('id',$id);
$smarty->assign('name',$name);

$smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
    ?>
```

I have tpl file called `testfunction.tpl`

```
<body>

<ul>
{$id}
 :
 {$name}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the `testfun.php` I got this output:

```
16 : dg
```

But I want output like:

```
1:d
d:g
```

What should I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value in smarty template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920553/getting-value-in-smarty-template)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your data as an array to smarty. So in PHP you should do something like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
  $data[] = array(
    "id" => $row[0],
    "name" => $row[1]
  );
}

$smarty->assign("data", $data);
```

Then, in your Smarty template you have to use [foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) to list your items:

```
{foreach $data as $item}
  {$item.id}:{$item.name}
{/foreach}
```