# Getting value in smarty template

Tags: smarty

I have php file called `testfun.php`. Which is getting values from the databse

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("unabke to connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("smartyform",$conn) or die("databse error");

require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$sel=mysql_query("select * from form"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
$id=$row[0];
$name=$row[1];
}
$smarty->assign('id',$id);
$smarty->assign('name',$name);

$smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
    ?>
```

I have tpl file called `testfunction.tpl`. I am getting output in this file

```
<body>

<ul>
{$id}
 :
 {$name}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the `testfun.php` I got this output:

```
16 : dg
```

But I want output like:

```
1:d
d:g
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Store your data in an array. So you have to do a for loop in your tpl.

It would be like this in your tpl:

```
 <ul>
    {foreach from=$your_data item=item_value key=key}
            <li> { $key } : {$item_value}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

In your php make it this way:

```
     require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

    $smarty = new Smarty;
    $your_row= array();
    $sel=mysql_query("select * from form"); 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
    {
       $your_row[]= $row;
    }
    $smarty->assign('your_data',$your_row);
    $smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
 ?>
```

View this page for a more detailed information:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach

Hope that helps you.

Comment: And i think, this one is helpful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921332/returning-database-value-in-smarty?rq=1 . They are the same as what you need, I think