# Returning database value in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have this Smarty code to fetch data:

```
$sel=mysql_query("select id, name from form");
$smarty->assign('contact', mysql_fetch_row($sel));
$smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
```

My template file:

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=$contact item=foo}
        <li>{$foo}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

This outputs:

```
 1
 a
```

But I want the output to be like:

```
1:a
2:b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), it does exactly what it says - it fetches a row, but not more than one. My guess is your result set looks like this (if I'm mistaken, please clarify in your question):

```
id  | name
----+------------
 1  | a
 2  | b
```

A way of getting around this is to build up an array which you then can take apart with Smarty, something like this:

```
/* PHP code */
$your_array = array();

$sel=mysql_query("select id, name from form");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
   $your_array[] = $row;
}

$smarty->assign('contact', $your_array);
$smarty->display('testfunction.tpl');
```

You now have an array in Smarty which basically looks like this:

```
[1] => (
     [0] => 1, 
     [1] => a
),

[2] => (
     [0] => 2, 
     [1] => b
)
```

This can be displayed like you described it:

```
{* Smarty Code *}
<ul>
    {foreach from=$contact item=foo}
        <li>{$foo[0]}: {$foo[1]}</li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

I haven't tried it, but it should do the job. If it doesn't properly, use a `{debug}` in your template to see how the array `$contact` is formed.

**Another word of advice:**

PHPs mysql connector, which you're using here, is deprecated. Use of this extension is highly discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.